# When I Block the Site , Still I am able to see the geolocation of the Browser using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I allow browser to get the Geolocation upon button Click, I am able to see the Latitude and Longitude. But when I block the site for accessing location, I am getting "Unable to retrieve your location" and Latitude and Longitude as well ... Here When I Block the site, I should get only message "Unable to retrieve your location" and Latitude and Longitude should not show...Please find the Screenshot as well[image]

Here is my Code

```
const GeolocationButton = () => {
    const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
    const [lng, setLng] = useState(null);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  
    const getLocation = () => {
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
      } else {
        setStatus('Please allow brower to access your Location');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          setStatus(null);
          setLat(position.coords.latitude);
          setLng(position.coords.longitude);
        }, () => {
          setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
        });
      }
    }
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={getLocation}>Get Location</button>
        <h1>Coordinates</h1>
        <p>{status}</p> 
        {lat && <p>Latitude: {lat}</p>}
        {lng && <p>Longitude: {lng}</p>}
      </div>
    );
}

export default GeolocationButton
```

Comment: `{!status && lat && <p>Latitude: {lat}</p>}`

Answer (score 0):

`lat` and `lng` are state variables, and state is, well, persistent. Consequently, when you set `lat` and `lng`, they retain those values, even if you later block access to location data.

There are various ways to resolve:

1. Since `status`, `lat` and `lng` are all interdependent, use a single state variable to store all three. This approach best realizes the dependent relationship between the variables.

   ```
    const GeolocationButton = () => {
        // could also initialize location to `{}`
        const [location, setLocation] = useState({status:null,lat:null,lng:null});

        const getLocation = () => {
            if (! navigator.geolocation) {
                // don't spread previous state into new state, and 
                // no need to explicitly set location.lat & .lng
                setLocation({
                    status: 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser',
                });
            } else {
                …
   ```
2. When setting `status`, also set `lng` and `lat`. This doesn't explicitly implement the interdependency between variables, and so requires more discipline on the part of the programmer.

   ```
   if (! navigator.geolocation) {
       setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
       setLat(null);
       setLng(null);
   } else {
       // note: there's a typo in "browser" in the question sample
       setStatus('Please allow browser to access your Location');
       setLat(null);
       setLng(null);
       …
   ```
3. When getting the location, initialize `lat` and `lng` to `null`:

   ```
    const getLocation = () => {
       setLat(null);
       setLng(null);
   ```
4. When displaying `lat` and `lng`, check that `status` isn't set (you should also check `status` before displaying it):

   ```
    { status ? <p>{status}</p>
    {!status && lat && <p>Latitude: {lat}</p>}
   ```

   or:

   ```
    { status
        ? <p>{status}</p>
        : <>
            {lat && <p>Latitude: {lat}</p>}
            {lng && <p>Longitude: {lng}</p>}
          </>
    }
   ```